# Difference between JSON line and Document Type

Tags: json, parsing, amazon-s3, line, document

can Someone help me to understand what is the difference between JSON Line and JSON Document Type? Can someone Provide me an example of the same?
I am trying to build a JSON parser.
I have tried to do google about it, didn't find any Satisfied answer to this problem. I have seen these term getting used in Amazon S3 Select document, but this doesn't make any sense to me.
Link to AWS document which I found on google is: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectSELECTContent.html

Answer (score 2):

It’s possible to represent any JSON on a single line. This is difficult for humans to read, though, so we’re more familiar with the multi-line “pretty” version. For a storage-and-retrieval solution like S3, though, it’s much simpler to blindly read a whole line and return/store it than to have to parse a JSON line-by-line until the first opening `{` is finally closed (`}`)

This is why it’s important to tell S3 how you’re storing and retrieving the files. From the docs you linked:

> LINES means that each line in the input data contains a single JSON object. DOCUMENT means that a single JSON object can span multiple lines in the input. Using DOCUMENT might result in slower performance in some cases.